# Genetic algorithm with matlab how to use classification accuracy as fitness function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, classification, genetic-algorithm

I have a problem which I want to solve with matlab Genetic algorithm toolbox and I dont know how to solve it.
I want to calculate 3 coefficient in a formula in a way that it maximizes a function which is the classification accuracy of a SVM classification model. the formula of the coefficients is a*A+b*B+c*C in which a,b,c are the coefficients which I want to find their optimized value and A,B,C are the value of 3 attributes of the dataset. I also have the constraint a+b+c=1 and a,b,c>0

How should I use genetic algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Generate a bunch of functions with that same formula, but with different coefficients. Then test them using some evaluation function keep the two functions that perform the best and generate the next generation from them.

Comment: Thank you for the response but i also need to know how to do it with matlab.How should I use the constraints in ga and how should I encode the fitness function?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to randomly generate an initial feasible solutions, as the first generation.

Each of these feasible solutions should satisfy `a + b + c = 1` and `a, b, c > 0`.

Then based on your fitness function, evaluation each of the answers, and choose the better ones as "parents". Apply GA techniques such as "cross-over" or "mutation" on these parents, to yield a group of offspring, as the next generation.

Repeat this process for a set amount of times, say, for 500 generation.

For example, you could define a variable `fitness`, the higher value means its corresponding candidate is a more suitable solution. Since you are maximizing this function, then:

fitness = a * A + b * B + c * C

In each of your GA operations (cross-over, mutation, etc), remember to always yield new candidates that satisfy your initial constraints (`a + b + c = 1` and `a, b, c > 0`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience one of the best solution for it is implementing the GA of MATLAB. The GA toolbox is generated to looking for minimum of such this function but by using symmetry, it leads to maximize of the function which your are looking for. Follow these steps:

- A,B, C = input data
- Normalize a,b,c which leads to a+b+c=1
- Your fitness function is a*A+b*B+c*C and define it
- Define nvars which for you is 3
- Put LB (lower boundary) in your case [0 0 0] which is a,b,c>0
- Run [x, fval]=ga(...) there for x will be final result x=[a b c]

If there were any question please e-mail me for more help: mahdigh242@yahoo.com

Hope the best